# Isolating a link with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have to scrape through the text of a website: [link](https://crmhelpcenter.gitbook.io/wahi-digital/getting-started/readme). I created a set using beautifulsoup of all the links on the page and then eventually I want to iterate through the set.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://crmhelpcenter.gitbook.io/wahi-digital/getting-started/readme'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a')
check = []
for link in links:
    link = 'https://crmhelpcenter.gitbook.io' + link.get('href')
    check.append(link)
print(check)
```

With this method it is not adding the sub-links of some of the links in the sidebar. I could loop through  each page and add the links accordingly but then I have to go through each link again and check if it is included in a set which makes the time expensive. Is there any way I can instead just isolate the "next" link that is on each page and go through that recursively till I reach the end?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can instead just isolate the "next" link that is on each page and go through that recursively till I reach the end?

If you mean buttons like

| [image: next_1] |
| --- |
|  |
| **OR** |
|  |
| [image: next_2] |

then you can look for `a` tags with `data-rnwi-handle="BaseCard"` and [because "Previous" button has the same attribute] containing "Next" as as the first [[stripped] string](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) (see `aNxt` below). You don't need to utilize recursion necessarily - since each page has just one "Next" [at most], a `while` loop should suffice:

```py
# from urllib.parse import urljoin # [ if you use it ]

rootUrl = 'https://crmhelpcenter.gitbook.io'
nxtUrl = f'{rootUrl}/wahi-digital/getting-started/readme'
nextUrls = [nxtUrl]
# allUrls = [nxtUrl] # [ if you want to collect ]
while nxtUrl:
    resp = requests.get(nxtUrl)
    print([len(nextUrls)], resp.status_code, resp.reason, 'from', resp.url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')

    ### EXTRACT ANY PAGE DATA YOU WANT TO COLLECT ###
    # pgUrl = {urljoin(nxtUrl, a["href"]) for a in soup.select('a[href]')}
    # allUrls += [l for l in pgUrl if l not in allUrls]

    aNxt = [a for a in soup.find_all(
        'a', {'href': True, 'data-rnwi-handle': 'BaseCard'}
    ) if list(a.stripped_strings)[:1]==['Next']]
    
    # nxtUrl = urljoin(nxtUrl, aNxt[0]["href"]) if aNxt else None
    nxtUrl = f'{rootUrl}{aNxt[0]["href"]}' if aNxt else None
    nextUrls.append(nxtUrl) # the last item will [most likely] be None
# if nxtUrl is None: nextUrls = nextUrls[:-1] # remove last item if None
```

On colab this took about 3min to run and collect 344[+1 for `None`] items in `nextUrls` and 2879 in `allUrls`; omitting or keeping `allUrls` does not seem to make any significant difference in this duration, since the most of the delay is due to the request (and some due to parsing).

You can also try to scrape *all* ~3k links with [this queue-based crawler](https://pastebin.com/t4scGj7C). [It took about 15min in my colab notebook.] The results of that, as well as `nextUrls` and `allUrls` have been uploaded to **[this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rMgkO9S1s_HKXBzJps5qfvrjVf-YtmqJ9Hp6_UFqGls/edit?usp=sharing)**.